# Good code for structure manipulation of table's cells/rows with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I'm writing wysiwyg editor (iframe in designmode), and I can't find good right code to operate with table. Not simple table where any cells have rowspan or colspan is 1! I mean about hard table variant, like this:

```
<table border=1>
 <tr>
 <td rowspan=2 colspan=2 width=60px height=60px>  </td>
 <td height=30px width=30px>  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td rowspan=2 width=30px height=60px>  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td height=30px width=30px>  </td>
 <td height=30px width=30px>  </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Any code I was found is only for simple tables. For example, this is code for insert rows and it do that wrong:

```
var cell = select.current;
var row = cell.closest('tr');
var table = row.closest('table');

row.after('<tr></tr>');
var row_new = row.next();

row.children().each(function()
{
    var cs = $(this).prop('colSpan');

    if ( cs == 1 )
    {
        row_new.append('<td>&nbsp;</td>');
    }
    else
    {
        row_new.append('<td colspan=' + cs + '>&nbsp;</td>');        
    }
});
```

I think the right code maybe will analyze all table rows and change rowspan values and etc.

Comment: There is Community edition of TinyMCE https://www.tinymce.com/pricing/ and demo https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/basic-example/#liveexample. Have everything you need.

Comment: I of course know about tinymce, but: 1) wrong working with cells 2) he hasn't ready-code like table operation class for my personal editor.